# What's expected from the answers to an app announcement post

Tags: discussion

The general model is to have the original post be a question and the rest of the posts to be an answer to that question. However, with the apps announcement posts, it seems that this pattern is reversed somewhat.

What would people expect to see in the answers to an app announcement post?

- bug reports and feature requests?
- general discussion on the application design?
- no answers expected?
- used by the app developers for updates on the app?
- for libraries - sample code snippets?

Comment: All of the above?  This site does seem to turn the "Question" idea on its head...

Answer (score 1):

I was actually going to wait to see a meta for this site before raising that. Given the available free hosting solutions for projects ([Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket), [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), [ShareSource](http://sharesource.org/), etc.) it's probably good if people do the following before announcing an app:

- Set up a bug tracker, else bugs become answers to questions that announce an app. Bleck.
- Set up *some* kind of discussion forum for the app. Otherwise there's bound to be 300 page long list of answers, which is actually 20 independent discussions all over the place. Bleck

In other words, it's probably good to have some kind of site up for the project, a place for people to get involved and most importantly a place for people to report bugs. This information should be posted in the announcement, which (probably) belongs on the meta site that (should?) be associated with this one.

If I'm not mistaken, this (new) site is supposed to be Q&A regarding the use, development and testing of the new API. So, it should probably be less 'on its head' than dev.meta.

Comment: Allow me to take this opportunity to put in a plug for Launchpad.net